# Center an image with CSS (horizontal and vertical)

Tags: html, css

I would like to take a logo image, centre it exactly in the middle of the screen, when keeping the image in its original size. Then right under that image (- 5px down), put a small text line, where I choose its font.

Everything is messed up when I am trying to do that, so I will put the basic. How can I achieve this simple goal?

```
<html>
    <body>
        <img src="images/logoBlackBig.png" alt="W3Schools.com" >
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want the image to be at full size and centered even if the window is smaller than the image, effectively cropping off the sides?

Comment: hi , the image is always smaller than screen , its a logo .but lets say i want to proportionally change its size according to screens .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Improved - now with image re-sizing

### Building Blocks

- The image and text are wrapped in a div.
- The div is centered thanks to the right combination of `position: absolute`, top, right, bottom, left and `margin: auto`.
- The container will re-size to its max width and height with `height: 100%` and `width: 100%`
- `max-height: 100%` and `max-width: 100%` ensures that the image width height ratio remains 1:1 when re-sizing.

**IE 8 needs a fixed pixel height for the container.**

Change max width and height to match the image.

### Demo

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: -4em;
  /* change top unit size to get desired vertical placement */
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100%; /*IE 8 Needs px height */
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 300px;
  max-width: 300px;
  min-width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
.centered img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered">
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/300" />
  <h1>Green Eggs and Ham</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You could achieve this by using css [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) and `absolute` position like this:

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/te55my5v/)**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border: 1px solid #000;
    text-align: center;
}
.img {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.p {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 24px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="div">
        <img class="img" src="http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m6cfbeVrUy1qegis6o1_400.gif" alt="W3Schools.com">
        <p class="p">MY TEXT</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks very much ,but again ,since i am a beginner ,how the ENTIRE html would look like with everything inside ?

Comment: @Curnelious You can add more content inside the `div` tag in my solution  and that will centre it exactly in the middle of the screen - http://jsfiddle.net/nvk0qkm8/

Comment: so what i do is just copy paste your code into the .html , the 2 parts of your code, and thats it? how can i add the text under that image?

Comment: i get it not centred ,i guess i am not writing it good, can't you just show me the entire file? how it should look like ?

Comment: thanks for the edit, its not good. the image is not centred, and there is html code appears on the page itself ....

Comment: +1 as always a rocking good answer

Comment: @Curnelious Copy and paste the entire HTML code from my answer in a new .html file and then run... :)

Comment: THANKS, its now working but not good, i see the image not centred in safari, and the text is above the image . . .

Comment: also if i take another image,bigger, it will put it not centred and too big(not resizing it)

Comment: thanks a lot , the code of misterManSam works  . . .

Comment: @Curnelious Try one more time in safari :)

Comment: @MaryMelody - I think he is using your fiddle which doesn't have `-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`. Safari needs the prefixed version :)

Comment: @misterManSam Yeah! maybe you're right but I'm so glad he accepted your answer. :)