# How to centralise images with an absolute position?

Tags: html, css, image, centralized

I have three images in a `<div>`. I want the images to overlay each other (for a slideshow using opacity) and remain central on my website.

To make the images overlay I set their position to absolute (`position: absolute;`). However, this conflicts with my method of centralising my images. To make my images central, I give images the following properties: `margin: 0 auto; display: block;` This doesn't work when the images' positions are set to absolute. What other methods can I use to make my images overlay and/or centralise images.

```
<div>
<img  id="SlideShow1" src="Images\image1.jpg" width="512" height="512">
<img  id="SlideShow2" src="Images\image2.png" width="512" height="512">
<img  id="SlideShow3" src="Images\image3.jpg" width="512" height="512">
</div>


img {
position: absolute;
   margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is by using CSS3 `transform`:

```css
img{
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,0);
}
```

Add vendor prefixes as needed.

This has also been mentioned in an answer under the question [Center an image with CSS (horizontal and vertical)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26316815/4642212).

Answer (score 1):

### See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/53dL9t5j/)

To centralize absolutely positioned items, use

```
left:0;
right:0;
```

along with `margin:0 auto;`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to setting automatic margins and absolute positioning, you also need to set all the offsets (top/left/etc) to 0. This method should work as long as you have a declared height:

```
.absolute-center {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

([source](http://codepen.io/shshaw/full/gEiDt))